# How to script copy and paste for a column with different values every few rows?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the table below in Link.

[Link To table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Dxmr.png)

On MS SQL 
How to copy and paste apples down the column until it hits banana and then copy banana down the column?

Same with the years, I want to copy and paste 2014/2015 down the column until it hits 2015/2016 and then copy that down the column until it hits 2016/2017 etc etc.

I would like the end result to look like something in the next link

[Wanted outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rhhWJ.png)

I Have about 30,000 rows that this needs to be done for, is there a quick way or known terminology for this as I could not find online.

Comment: You mention MS SQL Server, but tag MySQL... Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Just changed it now.

Comment: You need to give us more data than that. This may help too. https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/update-basics-in-sql-server/

Comment: How, by looking at your data, can we determine that the row `London |  |  | 43` belongs to year `2014/2015` and not any other year. Do you have any other field here (not shown) that can establish the sort order that you have in your example? If not can you just clear out any record that has a NULL `productname` and then do this with a cartesian OR full outer join to a table of `week numbers`

Comment: I guess the real question in my comment is "How do you determine 'down' when looking at this data?"

Comment: This is the full data I have been given, essentially it has been given to me in a "not useful way"  as you can see the years go from 2014/2015 to 2015/2016 and then it goes back to 2014/205 and starts again when there is a new product name. The trouble is filling in the blank cells until a new product name appears, then carry on the next blank cells with the new product name. <br><br> As for the dates, they just recycle.

Comment: Does the table has any identity column?

and what is the version of the SQL Server you use?

Comment: There is no identity column only literally the information I have been given.  I am using MS SQL server 2014. This table comes from excel as it is. I thought it be interesting to see how to play around with the data in SQL. I can't figure out how to copy and paste the data in the one column until it reaches the next word (which copy and paste process proceeds again)